# How to get file names from Ajax fileupload control in gridview in asp.net. (Remember its ajax fileupload control)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have used Ajax fileupload control in gridview, to upload files for each record in the gridview. I used ajax fileupload control, because i needed the drag and drop upload facility too. Its working awesome. 
But now once a file is selected in each row i want to get file names from the fileupload controls which are in every row within the gridview.

I have googled alot, how i could get uploaded file names on a button by name "Next" click, but i found no solution. Here is my GridView with Ajax fileupload control.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gvImgsSelect" autogeneratecolumn="false" runat="server"> 
  <Columns>
  
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campus">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCampusName" runat="server" Text="<%#Bind('campusName') %>"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
  
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image1">
    <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajxFileUpload1" width="200px" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"/> 
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns> </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" onclick="btnNext_Click" />
```

Is there anyone who wants to help me in this regards please. :(

Comment: Your question is a bit confused. Try to reformulate it and state exactly what you did and tried using examples.

Comment: i have used AJAX FILEUPLOAD CONTROL, in ASP.NET GRIDVIEW. Now i just want to get those file names of AJAX FILEUPLOAD CONTROL Within gridview. How can i get?  hope it is clear now. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
protected void ajxFileUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    // full path of uploaded file
    string filePath = e.FileName;

    // only file name of uploaded file
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
}
```